# Understanding finding max value with index in postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, max

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE foo
(
  c1 integer,
  c2 text
)
```

created as follows:

```
CREATE INDEDX ON foo(c2);

INSERT INTO foo
  SELECT i, md5(random()::text)
  FROM generate_series(1, 1000000) AS i;
ANALYZE baz;
```

Now, I tried the query:

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) SELECT MAX(c2) FROM foo;
```

and got the following plan:

```
Result  (cost=0.08..0.09 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.574..0.574 rows=1 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared read=5
  InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
    ->  Limit  (cost=0.00..0.08 rows=1 width=33) (actual time=0.570..0.571 rows=1 loops=1)
          Buffers: shared read=5
          ->  Index Only Scan Backward using foo_c2_idx on foo  (cost=0.00..79676.27 rows=1000000 width=33) (actual time=0.569..0.569 rows=1 loops=1)
                Index Cond: (c2 IS NOT NULL)
                Heap Fetches: 1
                Buffers: shared read=5
```

What I was really confused by is that the resulting cost was just `0.08.. 0.09`. Why?

I thought to find the `max`, if we had an index on the column we had to perform `Index Only Scan` and read at least one of the index leafs. Reading the leafs in turn accomplished with 1 random acces which costs 4. So, the cost should have been more than 4.

What did I miss here?

Comment: What is `CREATE INDEDX ON foo();` supposed to be doing?  I thought a column name was needed for index creation.

Comment: There is a semicolon missing from your table definition. And what is `baz` ?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Well, it's just a typo. Hould have been `CREATE INDEX ON foo(c2)`

Answer (score 2):

The cost of the index scan is pro-rated by the LIMIT.  The proration logic does not try to take rounding up of page accesses into integers into account, as at the point that the proration is done it has all just been collapsed to a single floating point number.